# Cannot launch Zoom meeting links

Tags: firefox, zoom-meeting

Recently, Zoom meeting links have stopped working for me. Up until about 2 weeks ago, I could click a Zoom link in Firefox and launch the Zoom application. Now, I am brought to a landing page with a button to "Launch Meeting" which does nothing, or links to "Try it in the browser".

I have seen similar questions answered by explaining that the Firefox installation in current versions of Ubuntu is a snap and blocks access to other apps, but I don' think that's the issue here for a few reasons:

- I have been running Ubuntu 22.04 for almost a year, with the Firefox snap, and have been able to launch meetings. This is a recent change.
- I have a second machine, with the same version of Ubuntu, Firefox and Zoom and this works

In my firefox settings, "zoommtg" links are set to use "default system handler" on both machines, but on the problematic one, this doesn't do anything.

I suspect I may have messed something up in trying to fix a separate problem. Zoom is a CPU hog and sometimes locks up when on long meetings with lots of participants and screen sharing. I was trying to create a local .desktop launcher to start zoom with a cgroup slice to limit CPU usage, but couldn't get it working, so I left the original .desktop launcher in place and got rid of my local changes. I can't recall if this new issue lines up with this new link problem, but it's all I can think of at the moment.

How can I inspect the interface between Firefox and system handlers? Are these events logged somewhere? I think it would be helpful to see this on my working machine and try to compare it to the one that doesn't work.

Basic details:

- OS: ubuntu 22.04
- FF: 113.0.2
- Zoom: 5.14.7